# Docker compose unable to load sh script on windows

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, sh

I added a external sh script on entry point of my postgres container but that external sh script was throwing syntax error. I'm using windows 10 OS.

Answer (score -1):

Open your script on notepad ++ and save it in a UNIX standard, it'll fix the issue.